# How to edit a vector mask in Photoshop CS2?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

This will sound astronomically simple, and you will indeed wonder how is it possible that I've never learned it. But: How do I quickly edit a vector mask in CS2?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To edit a vector mask, choose the *white* arrow Path tool (shortcut: A, then Shift-A if the black arrow tool is selected) and click on the path. You can adjust the anchor points and bezier handles from there.